# Add a .java file in a jsp or run a java file in a .js

Tags: java

I have create a Netbeans project in which I want to execute a Java file. To do that I have create an

```
input type="button"
```

that is contained in a form. If the user clicks on button he is redirected to a page called barrier.jsp (with the action=barrier.jsp).  On this page I have imported a java class file that is located in

```
WEB_inf/classes/nameofmyjavapackage
```

The only problem that I have is that the file is imported but it doesn't run. In fact, my Java file has to delect a directory but it doesn't do anything. If I compile the Java file by shell It works.

MY jsp is this:

```
 <html>
     <head>
         <%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
         <%@ page import="cancelladirettory.cancelladir" %>

         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>BARRIER REMOVE!</h1>
     </body> </html>
```

My java file is this:

```
 import java.io.File;


 public class cancelladir {
     private static void DelDir(String dir)   {

     boolean success = (new File(dir)).delete();
     if (success)
     {
       System.out.println("Ho cancellato la cartella: " + dir);
     }else{
       System.out.println("Impossibile cancellare la cartella: " + dir);
     } }

   private static boolean DelDir2(File dir)   {

     if (dir.isDirectory())
     {
       String[] contenuto = dir.list();
       for(int i=0; i<contenuto.length; i++)
       {
         boolean success = DelDir2(new File(dir, contenuto[i]));
         if (!success) { return false; }
       }
     }
     return dir.delete();   }

   public static void main(String[] args)   {
     DelDir("dir");
     String dir ="/home/lisa/graphhopper/europe_germany_berlin-gh";
     boolean success = DelDir2(new File(dir));
     if(success)
     {
       System.out.println("Ho cancellato la cartella: " + dir);
     }else{
       System.out.println("Impossibile cancellare la cartella: " + dir);
     }   } }
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.  Makes it much easier for us to help.

Comment: I have add the code, my java code try to DELECT, sorry, in my ask I have wroted detect :S

Comment: Please be sure to read the post formatting guide available under the giant orange question mark when working on a post.  You used quote formatting instead of code formatting...

Comment: Thank you for the edit... but I wish that is not the format of the code the problem to answer me...

Answer (score 0):

Your java class, if it runs in the console i'm assuming that you have a main() in there which then calls your code.

If you simply imported the class into your JSP it will do nothing without calling available methods from the class from your JSP inline code, but we will need to see your Java code and JSP file to verify this.

Lastly, if you were trying to work with the File System from a webapp, you might run into other security issues.